# kv syntax highlighting in emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, kivy

Can you get syntax highlighting for kv files in emacs?

If so, is it straightforward to do?

I'm new to emacs (used Geany 'til now), so please bear in mind I don't know my way around it to well and probably won't understand jargon, etc, but am keen to learn.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is correct (not sure why someone downvoted it).

It's also available in the [melpa repository](http://melpa.org/), `M-x package-install kivy-mode`.

Comment: thanks, this looks promising - though can anyone tell me how about the emac file I need to edit?  The one I search for in emacs gives me the file, but it doesn't have the text that MELPA asks for (package-archives,etc) so I can't get it working

Comment: Do you know about configuring emacs with a .emacs file? You need to add the melpa repository configuration there, then run the code (by restarting emacs or with M-x eval-region or similar), then you can do M-x package-install kivy-mode

Comment: Thanks inclement - I've got it running now - I added the code from melpa website to .emacs file, then did M-x list-packages.  Kivy mode was there in the list.  Great!  However, kivy mode uses red block for white space which is not ideal.   Thanks for your help (by the way, it was watching one of your videos that inspired me to go down the emacs route...)

Comment: It uses a red block for tabs. Use four spaces instead. You can set this to be the default in your .emacs file.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/tools/highlight/kivy-mode.el

I don't use emacs , but i think you can understand their installation .

Comment: you think i can understand it?  well, not yet, but I'll work on it.  Thanks for the reply.